# how to compare same file and send mail in linux

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, diff, cmp

I am creating bash script on a file to send `diff` over the mail.

for below case, I have created two files as `"xyz.conf"` and `"xyz.conf_bkp"` to compare
So far, I have come with below script -

```
file="/a/b/c/xyz.conf"

while true
do
     sleep 1
     cmp -s $file ${file}_bkp
        if [ $? > 0 ]; then
            diff $file ${file}_bkp > compare.log
            mailx -s "file compare" abc@xyz.com < compare.log
            sleep 2
            cp $file ${file}_bkp
            exit
        fi
done
```

I have scheduled above script to run every second

```
* * * * 0-5 script.sh
```

This is working fine but I am looking with different approach like below -
I am looking for to work without **creating another backup file** Imagine if I have to work multiple files which will lead me to crate those many backups which doesn't look good solution.

Can anyone suggest, how to implement this approach?

Comment: use a pipe.....

Comment: The backup seems necessary if you want something to compare a possibly changing file against. Is it `compare.log` that you want to avoid creating?

Comment: Hi @chepner, compare.log I'm using to send diff to me over mail. can we avoid it and send diff directly to mail instead of writing to file. But if found many differences then it will be difficult to send that much diff o/p without using file. Let me know if possible

Comment: See my answer, where I pipe the (eventual) output of `diff` directly to `mailx` instead of writing it to disk.

Comment: isn't there any option like "$file" I can save with some "2|5 seconds before" -> save it to var and then compare this two vars. like below \n $file="xyz.conf" and $file1="5 seconds before $file", then do diff $file1 $file. I have checked with some links to store date like that but not getting closed with my approach..

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way.

```
while cmp "$file" "${file}_bkp"; do
  sleep 2
done
diff "$file" "${file}_bkp" | mailx -s "file compare" abc@xyz.com
cp "$file" "${file}_bkp"
```

I wanted to avoid running both `cmp` and `diff`, but I'm not sure that is possible without a temporary file or pipe to hold the data from `diff` until you determine if `mailx` should run.

```
while diff "$file" "${file}_bkp"; do
  sleep 2
done | {
  mailx -s "file compare" abc@xyz.com
  cp "$file" "${file}_bkp"
  exit
}
```

`diff` will produce no output when its exit status is 0, so when it finally has a non-zero exit status its output is piped (as the output of the `while` loop) to the compound command that runs `mailx` and `cp`. Technically, both `mailx` and `cp` can both read from the pipe, but `mailx` will exhaust all the data before `cp` runs, and this `cp` command would ignore its standard input anyway.

Comment: here, why I used "exit" like once it found difference it should come out of the loop, so I used exit in "if loop" only

Comment: In that case, you can drop the outer loop and the `sleep 1`; the code will stay in the inner loop until `diff` actually finds a difference.

Comment: Hi @chepner, above script keeps on sending me flood of emails with same change

Comment: Add `exit` after `cp` again to ensure the subshell running `mailx` and `cp` exits after the copy completes. I suspect that the pipe, being asynchronous, allows `diff` to run again before either `mailx` or `cp` completes, triggering a neverending series of output from `diff`.

Comment: Actually, that may not help, because if it is `mailx` that is running the next time `diff` is called, it will continue to read the repeated diff. I'm not sure I can fix this approach.